# Show in the textarea the content of the certificate associated with the selected registration type

Tags: php, laravel

I have a form that shows some radio buttons, each radio button corresponds to a registration type.

The user can selected a radio button (registration type) and introduce some content in the textarea and click "Save" to associate the content introduced in the textarea with the certificate associated with the selected registration type. So I have the update() method in the CertificateController for this.

My doubt is when the user select a specific registration type, how to show in the textarea the content of the certificate associated with that selected registration type (radiobutton), if the certificate content is not empty.

Like below its not working. Do you know how to properly achieve that?

Tables:

```
registration_types table: id, name..., conference_id, certificate_id
certificates: id, content
```

CertificateController:

```
class CertificateController extends Controller{

     public function create($id){
        $conference = Conference::find($id);
        $registrationType = RegistrationType::where('conference_id', $id)->get();
        $certificateID =    RegistrationType::where('conference_id', $id)->pluck('certificate_id')->first();
        $certificate = Certificate::where('id', $certificateID);

        return view('certificates.index')->with('conference', $conference)->with('registrationType', $registrationType)->with('certificate', $certificate);
    }

    public function update(Request $request){
        $certificateID = RegistrationType::where('id', $request->radiobutton)->pluck('certificate_id')->first();

        // if is not null just update the content of the certificate
        if($certificateID){
            $certificate = Certificate::find($certificateID);
            $certificate->content = $request->certificate_content;
            $certificate->save();
        }
        // else create a new certificate
        else{
            $certificate = Certificate::create([
                'content' => $request->certificate_content,
            ]);
        }

        $registrationTypeToUpdate = RegistrationType::find($request->radiobutton);
        $registrationTypeToUpdate->certificate_id = $certificate->id;
        $registrationTypeToUpdate->save();

        Session::flash('success','Certificate configured with success.');

        return redirect()->back();

    }
}
```

Form in the view:

```
<form method="post" class="clearfix" action="{{route('certificates.update', ['conference_id' => $conference->id])}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{{csrf_field()}}
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col">
        <label>Certificate</label>
            @foreach($registrationType as $rtype)
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input
                            {{ (old('radiobutton') && old('radiobutton') == $rtype->id) ? 'checked' : '' }}
                            class="form-check-input radio" type="radio" name="radiobutton"
                            value="{{ $rtype->id }}" id="{{$rtype->id}}">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
                        Certificate for the registration type "{{$rtype->name}}"
                    </label>
                </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <labe>Configure the certificate for the selected registration type</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="certificate_content" id="" rows="3">{{ $certificate->content }} {{ old('certificate_content') }} </textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn" value="Save"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: so the issue is that textarea is not filling properly with text?

Comment: Yes, when the radio button (registration type) is selected in the text area dont appears the content of the certificate associated with that selected radio button (registration type).